# How can i remove symbols from file in python?

Tags: python, file

I'm having a hard time removing this `"//!"` from the beginning of my sentences on the file that I'm trying to parse in python.

```
with open("dwe.txt", "r") as file1:
    for row in file1:
        print(row.rstrip('//!'))
```

Expected output

```
The flag should not process everything that was given at the time 
it was processing.
```

Actual output

```
//! The flag should not process everything that was given at the time 
//! it was processing.
```

Comment: You should use `lstrip` as opposed to `rstrip` if you want to start from the `left` hand-side of the line.

Comment: Note that `strip` or its variations are not appropriate solutions if you only want to remove exactly two slashes followed by exactly one exclamation point, since they will happily remove more than that, and in any order. For example, `"!//!/!!!/foobar!".lstrip("//!")` returns `'foobar!'`

Answer (score 2):

As @Kevin mentioned, `rstrip()`, `lstrip()` and `strip()` removes *all variations* of the included string until it hits a character that isn't matched, so it's not ideal for your operation.  E.g.:

```
>>> 'barmitzvah'.lstrip('bar')
'mitzvah'
>>> 'rabbit'.lstrip('bar')
'it'
>>>'rabbarabbadoo'.lstrip('bar')
'doo'
```

Try using `startswith()` instead:

```
with open("dwe.txt", "r") as file1: 
    for row in file1.readlines(): 
        if row.startswith('//! '):
            print(row[3:])
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Adam comments, you just need to change `rstrip` to `lstrip`:

```
with open("dwe.txt", "r") as file1: 
     for row in file1: print(row.rstrip('//!'))

>  The flag should not process everything that was given at the time //! it was processing.
```

Comment: Expected output

void wite_id
{
 The flag should not process everything that was given at the time 
 it was processing.
 return (requesting);
} 

Actual output 

void wite_id
{
 //! The flag should not process everything that was given at the time 
 //! it was processing.
 return (requesting);
}